# How to adjust Image size?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, size

I am positioning an image in the center of the page and the text on it in the middle. But image looks small. How to adjust its width and height in bootstrap?

```css
    .inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: #fff;
      padding: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">  
       <div class="img-text-container">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=+" class="img-fluid max-width:100% 
          height:auto" alt="Responsive image">
           <div class="text-center bg-text inner">
             <h1> acknowledge Nature! </h1>
               <p>Nature is the most important thing in the life 
                which is alive.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (view the result in full screen mode):

```css
    .inner {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      color: #fff;
      padding: 30px;
    }

    .img-text-container{
      position: relative;
    }
 
    .img-text-container img{
       width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">  
       <div class="img-text-container">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=+" class="img-fluid max-width:100% 
          height:auto" alt="Responsive image">
           <div class="text-center bg-text inner">
             <h1> acknowledge Nature! </h1>
               <p>Nature is the most important thing in the life 
                which is alive.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Image is covering whole screen . How to cover Image height only half of the screen . (width 100 % and height 50% of the screen)

Comment: you can try to set a max height for your image `.img-text-container img {width: 100%;max-height: 400px;}`

Comment: If height is less, then its not appearing in the center. I tried col-md-8. Image size is smaller but not appearing in the center.

Comment: Gave text- align : center to its parent but not working.

Comment: .img-text-container img {width: 100%;max-height: 400px;} – It's working.

Comment: How to align Image in center horizontally,  if Img class is col-md-8 ? Class center- block not working?